# ruby mechanize get all the link in a website that have a specific word

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, mechanize

I want to crawl a site but it just stop at the URL I give mechanize and it does not do a recursive crawl. The informations needed is on the 3rd level. first level has a calendar where each day is a link. The second level is the day of the month and the third level is the informations I need which is in the body (text).
The links are 3 level deep:

_ calendar page        (1st level)
    [image]

____ day of the month  (2nd level)
   [image]

________ page with infos/text (3rd level)

I don't go past the 1st page/level.

Here is my code :

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://mywebsite.com/calendarPageWithLinks.htm')
puts page.title
page.links.each do |link|
    puts link.text
    puts link.href
end
```

**UPDATE**
I were able to access the different levels. Here the code used (it is not optimal).

```
page.links.each do |link|
puts "--------------------------------- LEVEL 1 --------------------------------------------------"
puts link.text
puts link.href
if page2 = agent2.get(link.href)
puts "--------------------------------- LEVEL 2 --------------------------------------------------"

page2.links.each do |link2|
puts " ****** #{link2.text}"
puts " ****** #{link2.href}"
    if page3 = agent3.get(link2.href)
        puts "--------------------------------- LEVEL 3 --------------------------------------------------"
        page3.links.each do |link3|
            name = link3.href
        if name.to_s.include? 'mailto:'
            puts " --------- #{link3.text}"
            puts " --------- #{link3.href}"
        else
        puts " --------- #{link3.text}"
        puts " --------- #{link3.href}"
            if page4 = agent4.get(link3.href)
                puts "--------------------------------- LEVEL 4 --------------------------------------------------"
                page4.links.each do |link4|
                    puts " +++++++++ #{link4.text}"
                    puts " +++++++++ #{link4.href}"
                    name = link4.href
                    if name.to_s.include? 'www.somesite.com'    
                        puts " ///////////// GOT IT !!!! /////////// #{link4.href}"
                        counterInfo += 1
                    end
                end
                puts " -----------------PAGE4 "
            end
        end
        end
        puts " -----------------PAGE3 "
    end
    puts " ***********PAGE2  "
end
end

 puts " counterInfo =  #{counterInfo} "   
 end
```

Comment: You give the real site url because now there is no way to know that the site does not use Ajax calls or submiting forms or using javascript to render the page. Be aware that Mechanize does not execute js.

Comment: instead of page2, page3, page4 consider organizing it into methods, otherwise you'll go crazy